# some files cannot be found in the Linux server when I run using cron

Tags: python, linux, ssh, cron

I run my python scripts in a Linux server and they are run successfully when I run it on the remote terminal using ssh. But when I run the commands using a crontab file, it cannot find certain files that are installed in the server. What difference does it make when I run the scripts using cron ? The cron file is in the same directory as my python scripts. I'm using "raster2pgsql" loader that is installed in postgresql installasion folder. The error meesage is:

```
sh: raster2pgsql: not found
```

my cron file content is:

```
*/2 * * * *  /usr/bin/env python /home/testexe/LST.py >> /home/testexe/LST.log 2>&1
```

Comment: You should add a precise error message and/or at least one example of a file that it failed to find.

Comment: The working directory differs?

Comment: The user and rights can change too.

Answer (score 4):

Cron runs commands with a more "plain" environment than your terminal.  Specifically it may not include whatever setup is done in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile or similar, which often includes adding things to $PATH (or maybe $PYTHONPATH in your case).

You probably just need to set some environment variables at the front of your cron job, like this:

```
00 00 * * * PYTHONPATH=/foo/bar yourprog arg1...
```

Edit: with the added content now in the question, I'd say try something like this:

```
*/2 * * * * PATH=/foo/bar /home/testexe/LST.py >> /home/testexe/LST.log 2>&1
```

You should replace /foo/bar with whatever directory contains the `raster2pgsql` program mentioned in the error message.  If you don't know where it is, try running `locate raster2pgsql`.

Note that I intentionally removed the `/usr/bin/env python` you had there--that should go in a "shebang line" at the top of your script.  That has to be the very first line of the file, and should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Then, just `chmod +x /home/testexe/LST.py` to mark the file as executable, and you can run it without explicitly invoking python from outside--either in cron or the terminal.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm afraid I don't understand it well. What is `/foo/bar` ? Is it related to the Python installation folder ?

Comment: I'll expand my answer now that you expanded your question.

Comment: now I get this message `bin/sh: python: not found`

Comment: Besides I cannot build an executable file. I run the command and it just do nothing

Comment: Perhaps you need to also set PATH=/foo/bar where /foo/bar is the location where your Python interpreter is installed.

Comment: Thank you. But this time the earlier problem arises